# How to show that the unit ball of the dual norm is also polytope?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, polytopes

Assuming a unit ball for the p-norm that is a convex polytope. How can one show that the unit ball of the dual's norm is a convex polytope?

Comment: The unit ball of the dual norm is the convex hull of the vectors giving the fact normals of your original polytope.  (This is the polar polyhedron.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the polytope $P$ (for example a cube or hexaedron..), I guess it needs to be symmetric to the origo $0$ of the vector space ($x\in P\Rightarrow -x\in P$). $P$ is going to be the *unit ball* for the norm to be defined.

For each vector $v\ne 0$ (imagined as a directed segment from $0$), define $||v||_P=1$ iff $v$ is on the boundary of $P$, and in general $||v||_P:=\lambda$ for that unique $\lambda>0$ which satisfies $\frac1\lambda v$ is on the boundary of $P$.

Try to find out the unit balls of the standard norms on $\Bbb R^2$:
$$||(a,b)||_\max:=\max(|a|,|b|)\quad ||(a,b)||_1:=|a|+|b|\quad ||(a,b)||_2:=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

---

In a general normed space, the *triangle inequality* (together with the scalar multiplication) yields for $u,v$ vectors in the unit ball ($||u||,\, ||v||\le 1$) and $\lambda\in [0,1]$:
$$||\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v|| \le  \lambda||u||+(1-\lambda)||v||\le \lambda+1-\lambda=1$$
That is, the unit ball is *always convex*, in particular in the dual space.

It also follows that if a polytope $P$ is *not convex*, then the above construction of $||\_||_P$ will not satisfy the triangle ineuqality (hence, will be not a norm).

---

The dual space of $\Bbb R^n$ is also $n$ dimensional, hence isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, normally it is handled with *column vectors* in the original space and *row vectors* in the dual space, since for each linear $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$, as any linear transformation, $f$ can be identified by its matrix, which is now the row vector
$$u:=\pmatrix{f\pmatrix{1\\0\\ 0 \\ \vdots}, & f\pmatrix{0\\1\\ 0 \\ \vdots}, &\dots}$$
You should check, using linearity, that for each (column) vector $v\in \Bbb R^n$, we have
$$f(v)=u\cdot v$$
where $\cdot $ is the matrix product, which is basically the original *scalar product* of $u$ and $v$ vectors. Now, the dual norm of $||\_||_P$:
$$||f|| =\sup_{||v||_P\le 1}|f(v)|= \sup_{v\in P}|u\cdot v|$$
Now if $P$ is a polytope, i.e. is an intersection of halfspaces $H_1,..,H_k$:
$P=H_1\cap H_2\cap\dots H_k$, then this reduces to a $\max$ on the finitely many faces of $P$.

Try to illustrate the case with finding the dual norm of the above $||\_||_1$ on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Ok, it's still not answered if the unit ball in the dual is *polytope* or not. A polytope could be defined as a finite intersection of halfspaces.